# C#: How to make autocomplete source of text box is database or datagridview coulmn

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I got textbox and I want to add autocomplete source is from database or datagridview 
I use Visual studio 2010
Any one could help please??

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073558/set-autocomplete-in-a-textbox

Comment: Thank you I will go check now :)

Comment: Sorry Harish that didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

using TextChanged event

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          /* perfrom serach query to check if thier is similar words to 
           suggested it in the auto complete*/        
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammed that is smart answer and simple :)

Comment: I am new here please could you tell me how do you add the code box in the answer please

Comment: But wait if I add search query and the user forget to save is his work is lost ????? Please ANSWER

Comment: Even it didn't give exact answer but it done what I want but please reply my q in comment

Comment: what did you mean by "user forget to save  his work is lost "

Comment: My app is for stocking database ,, and I don't want him lose any work or could you give me the the search query because mine if I don't save datagridview then search is done and the recent is lost

Comment: Huh,, I really didn't try to code this part i use the visual studio  setting aha may be you need the query ,, the query  in SQL  Like @coulmnname + '%'